C# selenium Chrome options for user data not working
I am building a selenium app, and it is supposed to start some websites (of course), and I want to make that chrome have data so user doesn't have to log in and stuff. So I put this code from ChatGPT (I guess not my best idea):
string userHomeDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);

// Construct the path to the Chrome user data directory
string chromeUserDataDir = " ";
string profileDir = "Default"; // Change this if you want to use a different profile



// Check for different operating systems
if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT)
{
    chromeUserDataDir = Path.Combine(userHomeDir, "AppData", "Local", "Google", "Chrome", "User Data");
}
else if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Unix)
{
    chromeUserDataDir = Path.Combine(userHomeDir, ".config", "google-chrome");
}
else if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.MacOSX)
{
    chromeUserDataDir = Path.Combine(userHomeDir, "Library", "Application Support", "Google", "Chrome");
}




// Specify the path to the user data directory and the profile directory
options.AddArguments(chromeUserDataDir.ToString());
options.AddArguments(@"profile-directory=Default");
options.AddArguments("--start-maximized");

As you can see, firstly the user home directory is found, after that I check for chromedata location that is different for each operating system so I have if statement for that, and at the end the chromeUserDataDir is added to options.
But this code doesn't work.
Does anyone know why?

Someone please help?
